# Google Analytics - Grouping page views by page category (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking, pageviews

I think the title is pretty self explanatory. But here's the longer version:

Basically I have a site with permalinks that do not include the category they're in. Posts can only be in one category. So what I want to do is track page views and group them in Google Analytics by post category. How can I do this? I've approached the problem from a Page View and Event tracking point of view but with little joy.

Thanks in advance for help

Carl

Answer (score 0):

For data already collected you are out of luck. For incoming data you can create content groupings. Since your url do not contain a category you'd have to set the content group via code like this:

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'WP category');
```

How you would do this in WP depends a lot on how your GA code is inserted in the page (I think there are GA plugins that allow you to set the category as content group).